# linux: extract pattern from file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a big tab delimited .txt file of 4 columns

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
name1   1       2       ens|name1,ccds|name2,ref|name3,ref|name4
name2   3       10      ref|name5,ref|name6
...     ...     ...     ...
```

Now I want to extract from this file everything that starts with 'ref|'. This pattern is only present in col4

So for this example I would like to have as output

```
ref|name3
ref|name4
ref|name5
ref|name6
```

I thought of using 'sed' for this, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: you might want to take a look at awk for that, should be more appropriate

Comment: sed and awk would both be an idiomatic way to do it on linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `awk` is better suited for this task:

```
$ awk  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /ref\|/){print $i}}}' FS='( )|(,)' infile
ref|name3
ref|name4
ref|name5
ref|name6
```

`FS='( )|(,)'` sets a multile `FS` to itinerate columns by `,` and `blank spaces`, then prints the column when it finds the `ref` pattern.

Comment: I think @kent 's anwer further down is far better.

Comment: If pattern always in column 4 would be my chosen option also, +1 for @Kent

Answer (score 4):

> Now I want to extract from this file everything that starts with
>   'ref|'. **This pattern is only present in col4**

If you are sure that the pattern only present in col4, you could use grep:

```
grep -o 'ref|[^,]*' file
```

output:

```
ref|name3
ref|name4
ref|name5
ref|name6
```

Comment: I just noticed that and wanted to update my own answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I had was to first use `awk` to only get the 4th column, then use `sed` to convert commas into newlines, and then use `grep` (or `awk` again) to get the ones that start with `ref`:

```
awk '{print $4}' < data.txt | sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | grep "^ref"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(ref|[^,]*\),/\n\1\n/;/^ref/P;D' file
```

Surround the required strings by newlines and only print those lines that begin with the start of the required string.